# Is it possible to submit ajax form via Qt Webkit?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm developing a Qt application that contains an OpenStreetMap application as a HTML page and this page is able to access a database -via submitting an ajax form that contains the start and end dates of queries- in order to retrieve and visualize queries on the map. I would like to move this querying process to Qt from the HTML/Javascript part. Is it possible to do this via the Qt Webkit's evaluateJavaScript function or should I be using QNetworkAccessManager instead? I have tried the evaluateJavaScript way but so far I haven't been able to send my queries to database -Although calling some dummy js functions from the html file that show alert box works-.